# Concatenating column vector to a cell array

Tags: matlab, vector

I have a matrix in Matlab as below:

```
a =

     1   169   158   147
     1   104   165    66
   728   105   276    43
   950   113   971    40
     1   107   810    23
   227   133    48    15
   618   131   107    20

class(a)

ans =

    'double'
```

I want to add a column to this matrix. When I try this command, i get a wrong result:

```
A={1;2;3;4;5;6;7}
vertcat(A,a)
```

Answer is like below:

[image]

What I wanted was:

```
1     1   169   158   147
1     1   104   165    66
1   728   105   276    43
1   950   113   971    40
1     1   107   810    23
1   227   133    48    15
1   618   131   107    20
```

What mistake I am making and how to I fix it?

Thanks
P.S: I am new to Matlab

Comment: You dont have a cell array, you have a matrix. What if you define `A` as: `A=[1;2;3;4;5;6;7]`. Also, do you want to concatenate horizontally?

Comment: I am getting: `Error using vertcat
Dimensions of arrays being concatenated are not consistent.`

Comment: But yes, if i do `[A,a]`, it works

Comment: Because that is a `horzcat`, not a vertcat. You want to put the columns next to each other to the right, not to the bottom

Comment: Try `horzcat([A{:}].',a)`

Comment: yes, that works